# Make the InputAdornment of an Input unfocusable in Material-UI v1

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In Material-UI v1 I'm trying to avoid that if a user presses the Tab key while typing in an Input with an InputAdornment, the latter is focused. Instead, what I'm trying to achieve is that by pressing tab the subsequent Input is selected.

It was suggested to me to set the tabIndex property to -1 to avoid it being selected by tabbing but it doesn't appear to work.

```
<Input
    value={this.state.email}
    endAdornment={
        this.state.email ? (
            <InputAdornment position="end">
                <IconButton style={{ width: "32px", height: "32px", tabIndex: "-1" }}>
                    <Icon>clear</Icon>
                </IconButton>
            </InputAdornment>
        ) : null
    }
/>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have `tabIndex` in the wrong place. It's an html attribute, not a css property. Write it like so:

`<IconButton tabIndex="-1" style={{ width: "32px", height: "32px" }}>`

Comment: Just a quick note: setting `tabIndex="-1"` can result in a warning: 

```Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `tabIndex` of type `string` supplied to `ForwardRef(ButtonBase)`, expected `number`.```

I believe more correct would be to use `tabIndex={-1}`

Comment: Your answer was correct vs ChatGPT (they put tabIndex={-1} in the <InputAdornment> component), thanks :)